# Write JSON to a table in a single query

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a JSONB column in a PSQL table which contains large JSON objects (up to 700kb). I would like to get a nested array inside the object and write it to a PSQL table. All of that at best in plain PSQL. Is there a way of doing it?

```
{"a": "foo", "b": [{"c": 123}, {"c": 456}]}

// should become

id | data
1  | {"c": 123}
2  | {"c": 456}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your table's name is `table_name` and the jsonb column's name is `jsonbColumn`, this will do the trick:

```
with items as (
    select jsonb_array_elements(jsonbColumn -> 'b') as item 
from table_name) 
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, * from items
```

Answer (score 0):

That helped, thanks a lot. Just for the sake of completeness here with the write operation:

```
with items as (
  select jsonb_array_elements(jsonbColumn -> 'b') as item from table_name
)
insert into another_table (id, content) select item->>'c' as id, item from items
```